# How to multiply a 4-D Tensor by a 2-D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, matrix-multiplication

I have a  4-D Tensor [batch_size, num_rows, num_cols, num_values] with shape [N,60,60,1], and I want to weight the WH Dimension with a [60,60] matrix.
How can I do that?

Comment: Is this NumPy or TensorFlow? Can you show something of your code, so we have something to get started? Have you tried some method to solve this?

Comment: Also can you explain exactly what you mean by "weight the WH Dimension" here? Do you want to do a matrix multiplication, or an element-wise multiplication, something else...?

Comment: @Chen, if you have a new question now that this has been answered, then ask a new *separate* question, don't change this one as it invalidates all existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a  4-D Tensor [batch_size, num_rows, num_cols, num_values] with
>   shape [N,60,60,1], and I want to weight the WH Dimension with a
>   [60,60] matrix. How can I do that?

```
tensor * matrix.reshape( (1, 60, 60, 1) )
```

This will [broadcast](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/broadcasting) the matrix along axis 0 of the tensor.